# Use a content of a cell as a variable name

Tags: matlab

I've created cell full of string variables:

```
X{1,1} = 'TEST1A1'
X{2,1} = 'TEST1A2'
X{3,1} = 'TEST1A3'
...
X{120,1} = 'TEST8C5'
```

Each of them represent set of data from an experiment. I'm creating a set of 3Dmatrix containing that data and it would be great if I could use those strings as a variable names.

Would a function handle be the solution for this? I've never really used them before.

Comment: Can't you just index into that 3D matrix accordingly and avoid creating so many variables which would also clutter up your workspace?

Comment: One 3D matrix is already 4096x2x64 positions long and I have 125 sets of data. I believe it can be done, but I also want to learn what's the best way of pointing variable names, if needed. Not to mention I would have to some of the functions to make it work.

Comment: Extend that to a 4D matrix of `4096 x 2 x 64 x 125` and just index into that fourth dimension to select any set of data. For me this would be the most elegant and efficient way to handle such a data.

Comment: Wow - dynamic variables serioudly get a hard time, wherever you would look. Thanks for this, I'll try to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use a structure with [dynamic field names](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/).

To fill it up:

```
X = {'test1', 'test2', 'test3', ...};
my_data = struct();

for t = 1:length(X)
    my_data.(X{t}) = <<read test "t" from file or database function + parameters>>
end
```

You will end up with a structure like this:

```
my_data.test1 % //(contains a 2d or 3d matrix for test 1)
my_data.test2 % //(contains a 2d or 3d matrix for test 2)
...
```

To read dynamically you do the same:

```
% // read only one member
tmp = my_data.(X{2})

% // or read them sequentially
for t = 1:length(X)
    tmp = my_data.(X{t})

    % // do something with tmp
end
```

I certainly consider the structure with dynamic fields cleaner than the trick of using the `eval` function:

```
eval([X{1}, ' = <<read test "1" from file or database function + parameters>>']);
```

Comment: This looks beautiful and my first test run clearly show it can work. I'll mark it as a correct anwser, I was looking for this kind if solution.

Comment: @KrystianMeresiński thanks. I highly recommend [Loren's blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/). She regularly post useful tricks.